# Multiple files on an external drive converted to four 64K files

Tags: external-hard-drive

Need some assistance please. I purchased a 2TB external flash drive. I copied about 13,000 files from my hard drive to the external flash drive. The flash drive somehow converted these 13,000 files to four 64K files. I happened to still have the drive and put it in the USB drive, McAfee saw it and asked me if I wanted it to be scanned, I did. I was expecting it to scan only those four files but McAfee scanned the 13,000 files. How can I extract these 13,000 files from the four 64K files. I have a background in IT but I have never ran into this. I would love to get these 13,000 files back because I lost a lot of data that I needed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

James

Comment: I wonder if you have a fake drive, it's not really 2tb.

Comment: What kind of files are these four files? @LorenPechtel might very well be right about your drive being a “fake” flash drive. What make is your drive and where did you buy it? Did you try any data recovery tools?